# Nginx 405 not allowed on CodeIgniter login

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, authentication, nginx

I have an application written with CodeIgniter, that runs perfectly on my local server (MAMP).
Now I'm trying to use an Ubuntu server 13.10, but I always get the 405 error when I click on the login button.

Screenshot of the problem.
http://i42.tinypic.com/14e3sjc.png
This is my nginx.conf file:

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please post your NGINX configuration.

Comment: Minor point - I'd recommend you use imgur over tinypic.

Comment: Please check your error/access log for anything useful. I would guess that `nginx-naxsi` has something to do with it but we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

A few simple tweaks will get it working. First in your codeigniter config file set your index page to be empty, and your uri_protocol to be `REQUEST_URI`.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Then check your root location. My app has a trailing slash, and most example Codeigniter/nginx server blocks do as well.

Lastly in your try_files line, make sure you take off the =404 portion and just have this: 
`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`.

And if you get stuck, below is my working nginx sites file (and my config file is stock from the ubuntu install).

```
#Working server block below. 
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/my_app/current/;
    index index.php;

    server_name staging.myapp.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, but codeigniter will handle the 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```